# Hierarchical query with min value calculated at each level in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I've been working on this problem on and off for a few days now, and I'm getting nowhere.

I have a dataset that resembles this:

```
NAME                EXPIRATION          PARENT_ID    CLASS_ID           
Master Class           365                              1               
Second Class           366                  1           2                 
Third Class            355                  2           3                 
Fourth Class           1001                 2           4                 
Fifth Class            1000                 4           5
Sixth Class            999                  4           6
```

ect. ect.

I can use a hierarchical query to get a view of what classes are required under a certain class.

What I really want to know is what the minimum expiration date is for the current level and sub-levels of the hierarchy. The expiration is the minimum expiration of anything under it.

If I wanted to do this in a brute force manner, I could get the results of my hierarchical query back, then for each line run a query that looks like this:

```
select min(expiration_date)
from ( start with class_id = $EACH_CLASS_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_QUERY
connect by prior parent_id = class_id);
```

I'm picturing the result like this:

```
NAME             EXPIRATION                           CLASS_ID
Master Class      355 (Min of it or anything under it)     1
Second Class      355  ""                                  2
Third Class       355  ""                                  3
Fourth Class      999  ""                                  4
Fifth Class       1000 ""                                  5
Sixth Class       999  ""                                  6
```

I'm assuming there's a better way though?  Maybe?

Thanks for any help, I've been puzzling over this for a few days now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table:

```
SQL> create table mytable (name,expiration,parent_id,class_id)
  2  as
  3  select 'Master Class', 365, null, 1 from dual union all
  4  select 'Second Class', 366, 1, 2 from dual union all
  5  select 'Third Class', 355, 2, 3 from dual union all
  6  select 'Fourth Class', 1001, 2, 4 from dual union all
  7  select 'Fifth Class', 1000, 4, 5 from dual union all
  8  select 'Sixth Class', 999, 4, 6 from dual
  9  /

Table created.
```

Using the good old connect by syntax:

```
SQL> with t as
  2  ( select connect_by_root class_id as class_id
  3         , connect_by_root name as name
  4         , expiration
  5      from mytable
  6   connect by parent_id = prior class_id
  7  )
  8  select class_id
  9       , name
 10       , min(expiration)
 11    from t
 12   group by class_id
 13       , name
 14   order by class_id
 15  /

  CLASS_ID NAME         MIN(EXPIRATION)
---------- ------------ ---------------
         1 Master Class             355
         2 Second Class             355
         3 Third Class              355
         4 Fourth Class             999
         5 Fifth Class             1000
         6 Sixth Class              999

6 rows selected.
```

And if you are on 11g Release 2 or higher, you can use recursive subquery factoring:

```
SQL> with all_paths (root_class_id,root_name,class_id,expiration) as
  2  ( select class_id
  3         , name
  4         , class_id
  5         , expiration
  6      from mytable
  7     union all
  8    select ap.root_class_id
  9         , ap.root_name
 10         , t.class_id
 11         , t.expiration
 12      from mytable t
 13           inner join all_paths ap on (t.parent_id = ap.class_id)
 14  )
 15  select root_class_id as class_id
 16       , root_name as name
 17       , min(expiration)
 18    from all_paths
 19   group by root_class_id
 20       , root_name
 21   order by class_id
 22  /

  CLASS_ID NAME         MIN(EXPIRATION)
---------- ------------ ---------------
         1 Master Class             355
         2 Second Class             355
         3 Third Class              355
         4 Fourth Class             999
         5 Fifth Class             1000
         6 Sixth Class              999

6 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find minimum expiration date as part of hierarchical query then you could try something like this:

```
select t.*,
       min(t.expiration) 
       over(partition by connect_by_root class_id) min_expiration_date
  from your_table t
connect by prior t.class_id = t.parent_id;
```

To get distinct records wrap it with another query:

```
select q.*
  from (select t.*,
               min(t.expiration) 
               over(partition by connect_by_root class_id) min_expiration_date,
               level lvl
          from your_table t
        connect by prior t.class_id = t.parent_id) q
 where q.lvl = 1;
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can use different `WHERE` conditions in the outer query to get any desired result. In above example your resultset is only root nodes. If you slightly modify it you can get a full tree instead (preserving minimum expiration value as well):

```
select q.*
  from (select t.*,
               min(t.expiration) 
               over(partition by connect_by_root class_id) min_expiration_date,
               connect_by_root class_id root_node
          from your_table t
        connect by prior t.class_id = t.parent_id) q
 where q.root_node = 2;
```